# C Closing FDT after writing with fork()?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, unix, fork

I was having a discussion with someone regarding the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
// creates a new file having full read/write permissions
    int fd = open("myfile", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    write(fd, "haha\n", 5);
    close(fd); // line 6
    fd = open("myfile", O_RDWR); // line 7
    close(0);
    close(1);
    dup(fd);
    dup(fd);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        char s[100];
        dup(fd);
        scanf("%s", s);
        printf("hello\n");
        write(2, s, strlen(s)); // line 18
    }
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Father finished\n");
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

He claims that we are closing the same file twice which causes an error, but I don't see that.

The child process has his own pointers to the FDT and when he closes one of them he can close others with no problem (even though those others may point to same FDT)

Plus, this won't affect father too. Am I wrong? and do you see any problems regarding this?

Comment: Why are you using the term FDT to refer to a file descriptor?  It is aconventional and looks wrong in English.  Also, in English, it is conventional to keep the parent/child names gender-free — referring to 'parent' not 'father', etc. (grandparent, grandchild, sibling etc).

Comment: Note that the "Father finished" (preferably "Parent finished") line will be printed twice, once by the parent and once by the child (unless `fork()` fails).  The `dup(fd)` in the `if (fork() == 0)` block does nothing useful — it merely creates another file descriptor that will be closed as the program exits.  You don't test the result of most functions.

Answer (score 2):

In the first place, it is not an error to open the same file twice, either consecutively or concurrently.  It also is not an error to close any open file descriptor, no matter what file it refers to.

But I think your dispute is really about the effects of all the `dup`ing and `fork`ing. Supposing that all the function calls in this code fragment succeed (and you really ought to test that, not least because it would address your dispute) ...

> ```
>     fd = open("myfile", O_RDWR); // line 7
>     close(0);
>     close(1);
>     dup(fd);
>     dup(fd);
> ```

... you afterward have three distinct file handles all referring to the same open file description.  Closing one of these disassociates a file descriptor from the underlying open file description, but that does not invalidate the others, and the underlying open file description is not closed while any file descriptor is associated with it.

When that process forks successfully, the new child process acquires its own, *independent*, file descriptors, with the same numerical values, all associated with the same open file description as the parent's.  That is, when you successfully fork after the second `dup`, there are then *six* open file descriptors, all associated with the same underlying open file description -- three in the parent and three in the child.  The fact that the file descriptor numbers are the same in parent and child is inconsequential.  File descriptor numbers are a per-process property.

The child then `dup()`s file descriptor `fd` again, making (on success), a seventh file descriptor associated with the open file description.  The child then falls out the bottom of the `if` block and closes its file descriptor `fd`.  It terminates normally, with the result that all its other open file descriptors are also closed.

None of that affects the parent directly, except that the parent will wake from its `wait()` and proceed.  It will then close its own open file descriptors, one explicitly, and the rest implicitly when it itself terminates.

There is no multiple closing of the same file descriptor, but again, if you were concerned about that then you could check the return value of `close()` to determine whether it completed successfully.

Comment: If `close()` fails with any error other than EBADF (bad file descriptor), you've no idea what state the file descriptor is in.  You have to assume it is closed, but you cannot rely on that being the case.